# Any reason not to modify another class's variables?

Tags: python, design-patterns

`Forms` have `Fields`. `Fields` have a `Widget`. If a `Field` name is omitted, it takes the variable name specified in the form. For example,

```
MyForm(Form):
    username = Field(name=None, widget=MyWidget(args))
```

The field name would become "username". However, this can't be established until the form is constructed. Would it be so awful to set the `field.name` attribute inside the form initializer, but after the field has already been constructed?

Similarly, would it be so awful to set some `field.widget.xxx` attributes inside the form initializer to "pass in" some variables that are used in various functions inside the widget class? Or should I explicitly pass them in to each and every function call? Why?

Answer (score 3):

Some OO purists might perhaps object, but IMHO there is really no problem in setting public attributes in instances of other classes -- worst case, if later on you find that instance needs to take some action when certain attributes are set, you'll just turn the attribute into a property, so that a "setter method" is automatically called when the attribute is assigned to (just make sure to always use **new style** classes -- e.g. by inheriting from `object` when a class would otherwise have no bases -- so that `property` works properly when you need it!-).